# how to Insert multiple checkbox values of array into database

Tags: php, html

I am stuck with how to insert multiple array data of checkbox. I came across some code but I don't know how to implement them in my php code. How can I insert multiple data from checkbox in my database? Can someone help me? I really appreciate it. Thank you in advance.

### html code:

```
 <?php
include ('connect.php');

 $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM owner WHERE owner_username ='".$_SESSION['username']."'";
$result2 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql2);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
$id = $row['owner_id'];

$sql = "SELECT cat_id,name,gender,health_status,neutered,breed,color,age
 FROM cat WHERE owner_fk = '$id'";

$result = $conn-> query($sql);

if ($result-> num_rows > 0) {
while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" .$row ['name']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$row ['gender']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$row ['health_status']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$row ['neutered']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$row ['breed']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$row ['color']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$row ['age']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>" ."<input type='checkbox'  name= 'check[]' value=''". " 
    </td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
      echo "</table>";
    }
    else{

    echo "0 result";
    }
     $conn-> close();
     ?>
```

---

this is my php code:

```
  <?php

  include ('connect.php');

  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
for($i=0;$i<count($_POST["check"]);$i++)
   }

     $p_id =$_GET ['sitter'];
     $price = $_POST ['price'];
     $pickup_date =$_POST ['pickup_date'];
     $dropoff_date =$_POST ['dropoff_date'];
     $numdays = $_POST ['numdays'];
     $total =$_POST ['test'];

    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO cat_sitter(sitter_fk,cat_fk, price, date_in, 
    date_out,total_day, total)VALUES ('$p_id','".$_POST["check"] 
    [$i]."','$cat_id','$price','$pickup_date','$dropoff_date','$numdays', 
    '$total')" or die ("Error inserting data into table");

    if ($conn->query($sql2) === TRUE) {
echo "<script language='javascript'>alert('Succesfully Book.')
    window.location.replace(\"book_page.php\");
</script>";
}else{
echo "error: " . $sql2 . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: try `implode` function . https://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: do you want to insert the data one by one in row or with separator in single row? According to that I can suggest you the solution.

Comment: i want to insert data with separator in single row

Answer (score 0):

Use implode function

```
In your case replace $_POST["check"] with implode(',',$_POST["check"]) then it will work fine fine hope so
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implode and explode. You can use convert checkbox array into JSON and store in single field.

```
 // Convert Array to JSON String
 $checkArray = $_POST["check"];
 $checkJSON = json_encode($checkArray);
```

After you fetch its value from database convert JSON into array.

```
 // Convert JSON string to Array
 //$checkJSON is variable fetched from database 
 $checkArray = json_decode($checkJSON, true);
 print_r($checkArray);        // Dump all data of the Array
```